# How to Compare Two Images using Soap UI + Webdriver/Selenium + Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am trying to automate the verification of the images and content in Email. I am trying to do it through SOAP UI tool. The big challenge is, SOAP UI tool is having the option to implement groovy script.

Can any one let me know how to implement Compare two images in Groovy script using webdriver?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _"Compare two images"_?  You want to know if they're exactly the same?  For more of a similarity check, you could look at [pHash](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html)

Comment: Yes, Need to check the images both are same.